# Android selectableItemBackgroundBorderless

Tags: java, android

I want to use `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` but as it needs 21+ api i want to have 2 drawable files. One in drawable-v21 linking to `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` and another for android 4+ devices linking for exmaple to `selectableItemBackground`. How can i achieve such thing? Can i make drawable file linking to drawable in theme? Or i have to find these files somewhere in themes or SDK and just copy it?

Right now i'm just doing this programatically if sdk>21 but i dont like this, cause i have to write more code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using it like this.

values/style.xml

```
<style name="selectable_item_background_borderless">
  <item name="android:background">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

values-v21/style.xml

```
<style name="selectable_item_background_borderless">
  <item name="android:background">?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>
```

layout

```
<view style="@style/selectable_item_background_borderless" >
```

Answer (score -1):

create `drawable-v21` in `res` folder add your drawable file in `drawable-v21` with same name located in `drawable` folder see image below

[image: Sceenshot]

Comment: Well i know how to do this) Problem is to refer on `?android:selectableItemBackground` in these files.